should there be pad tokens in the prediction after using tgt_key_padding_mask in transformer decoder layer?
I am training a tranformer model to predict a table image's html structure. For batch training, I used pad to make the ground truth a fixed length. But I found that after softmax, the probability of pad is extremely high and the final prediction is all s. So I wonder should there be pad tokens in the prediction after using tgt_key_padding_mask in transformer decoder layer? If yes, maybe I should try to set ignore_index in CELoss to the index of pad?
I tried to predicted a table's html sequence and used tgt_key_padding_mask but found the prediction is consisted of all pads.
Here's tokenize code:
from typing import List, Union
import torch

PREDEFINED_SET = [" colspan=\"10\"", " colspan=\"2\"", " colspan=\"3\"", " colspan=\"4\"", " colspan=\"5\"",
                  " colspan=\"6\"", " colspan=\"7\"", " colspan=\"8\"", " colspan=\"9\"", " rowspan=\"10\"",
                  " rowspan=\"2\"", " rowspan=\"3\"", " rowspan=\"4\"", " rowspan=\"5\"", " rowspan=\"6\"",
                  " rowspan=\"7\"", " rowspan=\"8\"", " rowspan=\"9\"", "</tbody>", "</td>", "</thead>",
                  "</tr>", "<end>", "<pad>", "<start>", "<tbody>", "<td", "<td>", "<thead>", "<tr>", "<unk>", ">"]


class TagConverter:
    def __init__(self, char_set=PREDEFINED_SET, max_len=512):
        # tokens = ['[sos]', '[eos]']
        char_set = char_set  # + tokens
        self.char_dict = dict()
        self.char_dict.update({v: idx for idx, v in enumerate(char_set)})
        self.max_len = max_len

    def encode(self, src: List):
        assert isinstance(src, List)
        # add <sos>, <eos>, <pad>
        src = src + ["<end>"]
        while len(src) < self.max_len + 1:
            src.append("<pad>")
        src = ["<start>"] + src
        return self._encode(src)  # 输出序列长度为max_len+2

    def _encode(self, input: Union[str, List]):
        if isinstance(input, List):
            encoded = []
            for i in input:
                encoded.append(self.char_dict[i])
            return torch.tensor(encoded, dtype=torch.long)
        return torch.tensor(self.char_dict[input], dtype=torch.long)

    def decode(self, encoded):
        tags = ""
        for i in encoded:
            tags += self.char_dict[i]
        return tags


def parse_tags(tags: List) -> List:
    idxs = []
    for tag in tags:
        assert tag in PREDEFINED_SET, f"{tag} not in predefined sets"
        idxs.append(PREDEFINED_SET.index(tag))
    return idxs

import os
from pytorch_lightning import LightningDataModule
from tqdm import tqdm
import json
from typing import List

import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision.io import read_image
from torchvision import transforms as T

from .utils import TagConverter


class SynthTabNetDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, img_dir: str, anno_path: str, type: str, input_size=448, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        assert type in ['train', 'val', 'test']
        self.img_dir = img_dir

        self.mean, self.std = torch.zeros(3), torch.zeros(3)

        self.input_size = input_size

        self.converter = TagConverter()

        with open(anno_path, 'r') as json_file:
            json_list = list(json_file)
        print(f'loading dataset: annotation number: {len(json_list)}')
        self.data_dict = dict()
        data_idx = 0
        max_tags = -1
        self.max_boxes = 256
        for j in tqdm(json_list, total=len(json_list)):
            anno = json.loads(j)
            if anno['split'] == type:
                imgid = anno['imgid']

                # # 从简单表格开始（没有colspan和rowspan）
                # if "<td" in anno['html']['structure']['tokens']:
                #     continue

                # if len(anno['html']['structure']['tokens']) > max_tags:
                #     max_tags = len(anno['html']['structure']['tokens'])

                self.data_dict[data_idx] = {
                    'img_path': os.path.join(img_dir, anno['split'], anno['filename']),
                    'tags': anno['html']['structure']['tokens'],
                    'boxes': [i['bbox'][:4] for i in anno['html']['cells']], # boxes数量不相同会导致batch拼接时出错
                    'classes': [i['bbox'][-1] for i in anno['html']['cells']]
                }
                boxes_padding = [[0, 0, 0, 0] for _ in range(self.max_boxes - len(anno['html']['cells']))]
                classes_padding = [0 for _ in range(self.max_boxes - len(anno['html']['cells']))]
                self.data_dict[data_idx]['boxes'] += boxes_padding
                self.data_dict[data_idx]['classes'] += classes_padding
                data_idx += 1
        # print(f'max tags: {max_tags}')
        print(f'max boxes: {self.max_boxes}')
        print(f'data number for {type}: {len(self.data_dict)}')

        self.transforms = torch.nn.Sequential(
            T.Resize((input_size, input_size)),
            # T.Normalize(mean=(0., 0., 0.), std=(1., 1., 1.))
        )
        # T.Normalize(mean=(0., 0., 0.), std=(1., 1., 1.))

    def preprocess(self, img_path, tags, boxes, classes):
        img = read_image(img_path)
        img = img.float() / 255.
        tags = self.converter.encode(tags)  # 被填充至max_len+2
        scale = (self.input_size / img.shape[1], self.input_size / img.shape[2])
        img = self.transforms(img)
        boxes_ = torch.tensor(boxes)
        boxes_[:, ::2] = boxes_[:, ::2] * scale[0]
        boxes_[:, 1::2] = boxes_[:, 1::2] * scale[1]
        return img, tags, torch.tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.long), torch.tensor(classes, dtype=torch.long)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_dict)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        anno = self.data_dict[idx]
        img_path, tags, boxes, classes = anno['img_path'], anno['tags'], anno['boxes'], anno['classes']
        return self.preprocess(img_path, tags, boxes, classes)



class DataModule(LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__()
        if args.phase == 'train':
            self.train_data = SynthTabNetDataset(
                img_dir=args.img_path,
                anno_path=args.gt_path,
                type='train',
                input_size=args.input_size,
            )
        elif args.phase =='test':
            self.test_data = SynthTabNetDataset(
                img_dir=args.img_path,
                anno_path=args.gt_path,
                type='test',
                input_size=args.input_size,
            )

        self.num_workers = args.num_workers
        self.batch_size = args.batch_size

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.train_data, num_workers=self.num_workers, batch_size=self.batch_size)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.test_data, num_workers=self.num_workers, batch_size=self.batch_size)

Here's model code:
import math
import torch
from torch import nn, Tensor
import torchvision
from ..datas.utils import PREDEFINED_SET
from positional_encodings.torch_encodings import PositionalEncoding1D, PositionalEncoding2D, Summer


class FeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoded_image_size=28, device='cuda'):
        super(FeatureExtractor, self).__init__()
        self.enc_image_size = encoded_image_size

        resnet = torchvision.models.resnet18()

        # Remove linear and pool layers (since we're not doing classification)
        modules = list(resnet.children())[:-2]
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*modules).to(device)

        # Resize image to fixed size to allow input images of variable size
        self.adaptive_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((encoded_image_size, encoded_image_size))

    def forward(self, images):
        """
        args:
            images: images, a tensor of dimensions (batch_size, 3, image_size, image_size)
        return: encoded images
        """
        out = self.resnet(images)
        out = self.adaptive_pool(out)  # (batch_size, 512, enc_image_size, enc_image_size)
        out = out.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  #  (batch_size, enc_image_size, enc_image_size, 512)
        return out


class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features=512, out_features=4, hidden_dim=512):
        super().__init__()
        op_list = []
        op_list.append(nn.Linear(in_features, hidden_dim))
        op_list.append(nn.ReLU())
        op_list.append(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
        op_list.append(nn.ReLU())
        op_list.append(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, out_features))
        op_list.append(nn.ReLU())
        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(*op_list)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.mlp(x)


class TableFormer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            d_model=512,
            enc_nhead=4,
            enc_dim_feedforward=1024,
            enc_num_layers=2,
            dec_nhead=4,
            dec_dim_feedforward=1024,
            dec_num_layers=4,
            max_len=512,
            device='cuda'
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.feature_extractor = FeatureExtractor(device=device)

        encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=d_model, nhead=enc_nhead,
                                                   dim_feedforward=enc_dim_feedforward, dropout=0.5,
                                                   batch_first=True
                                                   )
        self.encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_layers=enc_num_layers)

        decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=d_model, nhead=dec_nhead,
                                                   dim_feedforward=dec_dim_feedforward, dropout=0.5,
                                                   batch_first=True
                                                   )
        self.decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer, num_layers=dec_num_layers)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features=d_model, out_features=len(PREDEFINED_SET))
        self.bbox_decoder_linear = nn.Linear(in_features=d_model, out_features=d_model)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=2)  # TODO (l, b, len(vocab))
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        self.attention = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim=d_model, num_heads=1, dropout=0.5, batch_first=True)

        self.mlp = MLP(in_features=d_model, out_features=4, hidden_dim=512)
        self.cls = nn.Linear(in_features=d_model, out_features=2)

        self.src_pe = Summer(PositionalEncoding2D(d_model))
        self.target_pe = Summer(PositionalEncoding1D(d_model))

        self.src_embed = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=len(PREDEFINED_SET), embedding_dim=d_model)
        self.tgt_embed = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=len(PREDEFINED_SET), embedding_dim=d_model)

        self.tgt_mask = nn.Transformer.generate_square_subsequent_mask(max_len + 1)

        self.pad_idx = PREDEFINED_SET.index("<pad>")
        self.td_a_idx = PREDEFINED_SET.index("<td>")
        self.td_b_idx = PREDEFINED_SET.index("<td")
        self.start_idx = PREDEFINED_SET.index("<start>")
        self.end_idx = PREDEFINED_SET.index("<end>")

        self.backbone_params = list(self.feature_extractor.parameters())
        self.structure_decoder_params = list(self.encoder.parameters()) + list(self.decoder.parameters()) + \
                                          list(self.linear.parameters()) + list(self.softmax.parameters())
        self.bbox_decoder_params = list(self.bbox_decoder_linear.parameters()) + list(self.attention.parameters()) + \
                                     list(self.mlp.parameters()) + list(self.cls.parameters()) + list(self.sigmoid.parameters())

    def forward(self, img, y_tags, y_bboxes, y_classes):
        # backbone part
        x_f = self.feature_extractor(img)  # x_f : (b, h, w, c)
        # x_f = x_f.permute(1, 2, 0, 3)  # (b, h, w, c) => (h, w, b, c)
        x_pe = self.src_pe(x_f)
        x_pe = x_pe.view(x_pe.shape[0], -1, x_pe.shape[3]) # (b, l, c) (1, 784, 512)
        # structure decoder part
        enc_out = self.encoder(x_pe)  # (b, l, dim)
        if y_tags is None:
            y_src = torch.tensor([self.start_idx]).unsqueeze(1).to(enc_out.device)
            terminal = False
            while not terminal:
                padding_mask = self.get_padding_mask(y_src[-1])
                dec_out = self.decoder(
                    tgt=self.target_pe(self.tgt_embed(y_src)),
                    memory=enc_out,
                    tgt_mask=None,
                    tgt_key_padding_mask=padding_mask,
                    memory_mask=None)
                dec_out_idx = torch.argmax(self.softmax(self.linear(dec_out)), dim=2)
                if dec_out_idx[-1] == self.end_idx:
                    terminal = True
                    break
                y_src = torch.cat([y_src, dec_out_idx[-1].unsqueeze(0)], dim=0)


        else:
            # y_src = y_tags[:, :-1].permute(1, 0) # (seq_len, batch_size)
            y_src = y_tags[:, :-1]
            # print(y_src)
            # y_src = y_src[(y_src != self.pad_idx) & (y_src != self.end_idx)].unsqueeze(1)
            # self.tgt_mask = nn.Transformer.generate_square_subsequent_mask(y_src.size(0))
            padding_mask = self.get_padding_mask(y_src)
            tgt_pe = self.target_pe(self.tgt_embed(y_src))
            dec_out = self.decoder(
                tgt=tgt_pe,
                memory=enc_out,
                tgt_mask=self.tgt_mask.to(enc_out.device),
                tgt_key_padding_mask=padding_mask,
                memory_mask=None)
            pred_tags = self.softmax(self.linear(dec_out))
            dec_out_ = self.get_tds(y_src, dec_out)
            # print(torch.argmax(pred_tags, dim=-1))
            # cell bbox decoder part
            linear_out = self.bbox_decoder_linear(enc_out)

            attn_out, _ = self.attention(query=dec_out_, key=linear_out, value=enc_out)  # q, k, v, 用linear_out代替enc_out

            attn_out = self.sigmoid(attn_out)
            pred_boxes, pred_clses = self.mlp(attn_out), self.cls(attn_out)
            return enc_out, pred_tags, pred_boxes, pred_clses

    def get_tds(self, src, dec_out, max_boxes=256):
        # src, mask (batch_size, seq_len)
        # dec_out (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)
        mask_a = src == self.td_a_idx
        mask_b = src == self.td_b_idx
        mask = mask_a + mask_b

        for i in range(dec_out.shape[0]):
            if i == 0:
                dec_out_ = dec_out[0:1, :-1, :][:, mask[0, 1:]]
                pad = torch.zeros((1, max_boxes - dec_out_.shape[1], dec_out_.shape[2])).to(dec_out.device)
                dec_out_ = torch.cat([dec_out_, pad], dim=1)
            else:
                cat_target = dec_out[i:i + 1, :-1, :][:, mask[i, 1:]]
                pad = torch.zeros((1, max_boxes - cat_target.shape[1], cat_target.shape[2])).to(dec_out.device)
                cat_target = torch.cat([cat_target, pad], dim=1)
                dec_out_ = torch.cat([dec_out_, cat_target], dim=0)
        return dec_out_

    def get_padding_mask(self, src):
        padding_mask = torch.zeros(src.shape, dtype=torch.bool).to(src.device)
        padding_mask[src == self.pad_idx] = True
        return padding_mask



Here's training code with Pytorchlightning:
import argparse
import torch
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

from torchvision.ops import generalized_box_iou_loss
from tableformer.models.models import TableFormer
from tableformer.datas.datas import DataModule
from tableformer.datas.utils import PREDEFINED_SET

from collections import Counter


class TableFormerLit(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__()
        self.lr = args.lr
        self.model = TableFormer()
        self.batch_size = args.batch_size
        self.l1_loss = nn.L1Loss()
        self.vocab_size = len(PREDEFINED_SET)
        self.tag_occur = [0 for _ in range(self.vocab_size)]
        # self.automatic_optimization = False

    def forward(self, x):
        """inference onlys"""
        _ = self.model(x)
        return None

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        # backbone_opt = optim.Adam(self.model.backbone_params, lr=self.lr)
        # structure_decoder_opt = optim.Adam(self.model.structure_decoder_params, lr=self.lr)
        # bbox_decoder_opt = optim.Adam(self.model.bbox_decoder_params, lr=self.lr)
        # # lr_schedulers = {"scheduler": ReduceLROnPlateau(opt1, ...), "monitor": "metric_to_track"}
        # return backbone_opt, structure_decoder_opt, bbox_decoder_opt
        structure_decoder_opt = optim.Adam(self.model.structure_decoder_params, lr=self.lr)
        return structure_decoder_opt

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        structure_decoder_opt = self.optimizers()

        image, tags, boxes, classes = batch  # tags tokenized
        # tags:(1, 514), pred_tags:(dec_input_len,1,32)
        # tags: <start>...<end><pad>...
        enc_out, pred_tags, pred_boxes, pred_clses = self.model(image, tags, boxes, classes)
        print(torch.argmax(pred_tags, dim=2))
        # structure decode loss : cross-entropy
        l_s = F.cross_entropy(pred_tags.permute(0, 2, 1),  # TODO 调整权重
                              tags[:, 1:pred_tags.shape[1]+1],
                              ignore_index=self.model.pad_idx,
                              # weight=self.get_CEloss_weights(tags)
                              )  # (b, vocab-1) : vocab : len([<start>,<end>,...])
        self.log("l_s", l_s)
        return l_s
        # structure_decoder_opt.zero_grad()
        # self.manual_backward(l_s, retain_graph=True)
        # structure_decoder_opt.step()
        # bbox loss
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        # l_iou = generalized_box_iou_loss(pred_boxes.permute(1, 0, 2), boxes,
        #                                  reduction='mean')  # TODO match size of pred and gt
        # l_l1 = self.l1_loss(pred_boxes.permute(1, 0, 2), boxes)
        # l_box = 0.5 * l_iou + 0.5 * l_l1
        # # bbox_decoder_opt.zero_grad()
        # # self.manual_backward(l_box, retain_graph=False)
        # # bbox_decoder_opt.step()
        # # total loss
        # loss = 0.5 * l_s + 0.5 * l_box
        # return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y, z = batch
        pass

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        image, tags, boxes, classes = batch
        enc_out, pred_tags, pred_boxes, pred_clses = self.model(image, None, boxes, classes)

        l_s = F.cross_entropy(pred_tags.permute(1, 2, 0),
                              tags[:, 1:])  # (b, vocab-1) : vocab : len([<start>,<end>,...])
        # bbox loss
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        l_iou = generalized_box_iou_loss(pred_boxes.permute(1, 0, 2), boxes,
                                         reduction='mean')  # TODO match size of pred and gt
        l_l1 = self.l1_loss(pred_boxes.permute(1, 0, 2), boxes)
        l_box = 0.5 * l_iou + 0.5 * l_l1
        # total loss
        loss = 0.5 * l_s + 0.5 * l_box
        return loss

    def get_CEloss_weights(self, tags):
        tag_counts = Counter(tags.flatten().tolist())
        for i, item in enumerate(PREDEFINED_SET):
            self.tag_occur[i] += tag_counts[i]
        weights = torch.tensor([1/(x if x > 0 else 1) for x in self.tag_occur], device='cuda')
        print(weights)
        print(F.normalize(weights, p=1, dim=0))

        return F.normalize(weights, p=1, dim=0)


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='TableFormer')
    parser.add_argument('--phase', choices=['train', 'test'], default='train')
    parser.add_argument('--img_path', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--gt_path', required=True)
    parser.add_argument(('--ckpt_path'), default="/home/zrl/projects/TableFormer/lightning_logs/version_287/checkpoints/epoch=11-step=60000.ckpt")
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=24)
    parser.add_argument('--num_epochs', default=24)
    parser.add_argument('--input_size', default=448)
    parser.add_argument('--num_workers', default=2)
    parser.add_argument('--lr', default=0.0001)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    # trainer = pl.Trainer.from_argparse_args(
    #     args,
    #     max_epochs=args.num_epochs,
    #     accelerator='gpu',
    #     devices=1
    # )
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        max_epochs=args.num_epochs,
        accelerator='gpu',
        devices=1,
        callbacks=[pl.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(every_n_epochs=1, save_top_k=1)]
    )
    if args.phase == 'train':
        dm = DataModule(args)
        model = TableFormerLit(args)
        trainer.fit(
            model=model,
            datamodule=dm,
            # ckpt_path=args.ckpt_path
        )
    elif args.phase == 'test':
        dm = DataModule(args)
        model = TableFormerLit(args)
        trainer.test(ckpt_path=args.ckpt_path, model=model, datamodule=dm)
    # if args.phase == 'train':
    #     trainer.fit(model)
    #     trainer.test(model)
    # elif args.phase == 'test':
    #     trainer.test(model)

